# How can I gain access to my deceased relative's Instagram account?

Tags: instagram

My uncle passed and my grandmother wants access to his pics on Instagram but his page is private. Is there any way I can gain access? I have visited many sites and have tried every hacking site known. I just need help to view his photos for my grandmother.

Comment: Have you contacted Instagram? I'm not sure what their policy is regarding deceased users. For what it's worth, this is why we all need to have a plan for our electronic selves.

Answer (score 2):

Per their policy, you can’t get login access to the account. However, you could try and ask for an archive of the photos.

> **8. HOW TO CONTACT US ABOUT A DECEASED USER**
>
> In the event of the death of an Instagram User, please [contact us](http://help.instagram.com/264154560391256/). We will usually conduct our communication via email; should we require any other information, we will contact you at the email address you have provided in your request.

[Source](http://instagram.com/legal/privacy/).

> **How do I report a deceased person's account on Instagram?**
>
> It is our policy to remove the account of a deceased person from Instagram. To protect the privacy of people on Instagram, we are unable to provide anyone with login information to an account.
>
> When you [submit a report of a deceased person](https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/contact/396019703850735), we require proof of death such as a death certificate or obituary.

[Source](http://help.instagram.com/264154560391256/).